# Conditional filtering for grouping

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, sequences

Not sure if the question is correct, as I'm having some trouble with what the term is for what I'm looking for exactly. Have the following data:

```
int? Sequence
Date theDate
int? anID
```

What I need to do is apply the following rules to this sequence `(LINQ)`:

- no 2 elements which have a `Sequence` have the same non-null `anID`s.
- no 2 elements have the same `theDate` and `anID`s if one of them has a `Sequence`.
- element N’s `theDate` is more recent than element N-1s `theDate`.
- element N’s `theDate` = element N-1s `theDate` AND element N's `Sequence` > element N-1's `Sequence`.

How do I manage this? Do I need to use nested group by's? Will this be conditional group by's?

Am a little lost on my implementation and terminology and will update question if I get a better understanding of the solution.

Comment: _"will update question if I get a better understanding of the solution"_ You should update your question so that we  better understand your requirement. Your _data_ are three variables, do they belong to a class?

Comment: show me some test data and excepted result